# Class compiler error: identifier expected

Tags: java, compiler-construction

I have to write a very simple class so that I can write an object. Originally, my code looked like this:

```
public class Pie{
    String flavour;
    String type;
    String size;    
}
```

But when I tried to compile I got 2 errors: `identifier expected` and `';' expected`.

Then I added the main method. So the code looked like this:

```
public class Pie{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String flavour;
        String type;
        String size;    
    }
}
```

And it's still giving me the same errors! Why?

Comment: Does your code look like that? Usually identifier error is because you are writing code that isn't wrapped in a block.

Comment: I do not get any errors when I compile the code exactly as you posted it.  If the compiler told you what line the error was on and perhaps what point in the line, could you provide that info?

Comment: Yes, it looks exactly like that, which is why I'm so confused about the error! Everything seems fine!

Comment: If you include JUST that second snippet of code in your ide and run it, what is the EXACT error you are getting (because the code that is there is fine).

Answer (score 0):

Public classes should be in the `Pie.java` source file, not sure what file name are you using. Also if you are using the package then the package name should correspond the path from the source root folder. It's just simple Java conventions to name Java classes and packages, and it's important to Java because without those conventions we have undetermined locations of files and file names by the source locations.

Comment: If the file name is wrong, that shouldn't produce the types of error messages the questioner is seeing.

Comment: It ended up being the file name. I've fixed it. My teacher explained it differently and completely confused me. But thanks!